# error message on the dimensions of matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

When I run this program, I get the error message:

??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in ==> if a(1,i)==0

could you tell me why??

```
a = randi(5,4,100)-ones(4,100);

[n m]=size(a);

for i=1:m
    if a(1,i)==0
        a(:,i)=[];
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you are removing columns from your matrix, so inside the for loop you are reducing its dimension. Then you try to access a column with an index which refers to the original matrix, before the columns were removed.

Try this instead:

```
a = randi(5,4,100)-1;
ind2remove = (a(1,:) == 0);
a(:,ind2remove) = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because during the execution of this `for` loop, you might remove some columns. Therefore the dimensions of the matrix will decrease and you will try to access elements that have been moved to a different place.

To do wht you want, you either have to write a `while` loop, keeping the indices in check manually. The other solution is to vectorize your solution as itamar Katz has shown. That solution is more MATLAB-esque than writig a `while` loop.

But I have noticed that allowing a random algorithm to emit vectors of random length can sometimes prove more difficult to handle than fixed-length vectors. So you might want to construct your vector in such a way that you don't even have to remove such entries, depending on your application this might be accomplished by generating the first row and other rows with different instructions.

Comment: the random vector was only to verify the accuracy of my program.